# In android web view the html page is being treated like it is being opened in a big screen rather in mobile device

Tags: java, android, html, webview, responsive

I am using a webview in my android app. Now the issue is in that webview it is opening like a desktop site not like a mobile platform site.

As for example, when I open the page in webview it is being shown like
[image: Mobile app webview look, where the page zooms out and things become very small]

And the same page when I am opening in web browser it looks like;

[image: Android web browser view where texts are zoom in and page becomes horizontally scrolable. Both are same html(please ignore the background color)]

Now my question is I want to open the page in my web view like it is in web browser and I have no idea why it is behaving like that.

My webview code is like;

```
    final WebView webview = (WebView)vi.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings set = webview.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    set.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    set.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    set.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    set.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    set.setSaveFormData(true);
    set.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    set.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    set.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    set.setSupportZoom(false);
    set.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");


    WebChromeClient webClient = new WebChromeClient(){

        public void onCloseWindow(Window w){
            super.onCloseWindow(webview);
            System.out.println("Closed");
        }
    };
    webview.setWebChromeClient(webClient);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

I changed the value of `webview.setInitialScale(1);` but no luck so far.

I can not change the HTML of the pages, so I need to do some kind of changes in webview end.

**N.B. The attached images of page is same HTML page opening in browser and webview. PLEASE IGNORE THE BACKGROUND COLOR.**

Any help will be very good for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initViews();
}


protected void initViews() {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getCertificate();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerantWebViewClient());


    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

}


private class SSLTolerantWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    // ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        Log.d("ddd", "ddd");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Is your page responsive ? Try opening page in mobile browser. if it is not responsive make it responsive. Make sure you have added viewport meta tag in html like -

Comment: Whether my page is responsive or not that does not matter. I want my page to be opened exactly same like mobile web browser.

Comment: But anyway "Make sure you have added viewport meta tag" this helps me. e.g. <meta name="viewport" content="width=350, user-scalable=no" />. Elaborate your answer a bit with details, then I can make this as right answer.

Comment: if your page is not reponsive you can make your page responsive by adding this view port meta tag. this is just not solution you have style whole page as responsive